# How did Instagram implement mutual followers/followings list feature?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, instagram

As you know, Instagram has huge amount of users(Maybe [2.35 billion MAUs on March, 2023](https://www.demandsage.com/instagram-statistics/)).

If I naively assume that there are 4 billion users in total and 100 followers per user on average, there would be 400 billion relationships in total.

According to [the article from Instagram on 2012](https://instagram-engineering.com/sharding-ids-at-instagram-1cf5a71e5a5c), they had been using PostgreSQL for storing basic data with sharding.
As you know, Instagram has a feature that you can see your entire followings list on some other user's profile.

[image]

Now that they have much more users, not comparable with that time, how could I implement this feature?

I thought of a table schema as follows,

```
table relationship {
  user_id bigint,
  following_user_id bigint
}
```

It must take too much to join if the user you're watching has hundreds of millions of followers. And you cannot read hundreds of millions rows on memory and iterate all the followings of mine and checking if it exists in some other user's followers list using HashSet(it might be too worst case, but BLACKPINK Lisa has almost a hundred millions followers, for example).

I also thought of using bloom filter to check if each of my followings are likely to be in a filter, so it would take O(min(# of followings of mine, # of followers of a user)) and # of followings is likely to be very small compared to followers, and then double-check with a query with IN clause because bloom filter is probabilistic data structure.

How would you implement this feature?

Comment: "How would you implement this feature?" - this is literally a System Design interview question in FAANGs. It takes an hour to only begin describing this.